# How can I instruct gradle to monitor `local.properties` to know when a `Gradle Sync` is needed?

Tags: gradle

I use `gradle.properties` and `local.properties` to inject configuration into `buildSrc`.

```
// in buildSrc
private val localVersions = LocalVersions.create()

object Versions {
  kotlin = localVersions.kotlin
}
object Libs {
  kotlin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${Versions.kotlin}"
}
```

```
// gradle.properties
versions.kotlin=1.3.21
```

This works great. But let's say I add this line to `local.propeties` (which should override the value in `gradle.properties`).

```
// local properties
versions.kotlin=1.3.30
```

When I build again, `Versions.kotlin` still returns `1.3.21`, because it does not realize that a change to `local.properties` will affect the buildSrc classpath.

```
private data class LocalVersions(
    val kotlin: String
) {
    companion object {

        private const val gradlePropertiesFileName = "gradle.properties"
        private const val localPropertiesFileName = "local.properties"

        private const val kotlinVersionPropertyName = "versions.kotlin"

        @JvmStatic
        fun create(): LocalVersions {
            val props = Properties().apply {
                fun File.asInputStream(): InputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(this))

                val gradlePropsFile = File(gradlePropertiesFileName).apply {
                    require(exists()) {
                        "File does not exist. ${this.absolutePath}"
                    }
                }
                val localPropsFile = File(localPropertiesFileName)

                if (!gradlePropsFile.exists()) {
                    throw FileNotFoundException("Could not find file: $gradlePropsFile.absolutePath")
                }

                load(gradlePropsFile.asInputStream())

                if (localPropsFile.exists()) {
                    load(localPropsFile.asInputStream())
                }
            }

            fun findProperty(name: String): String {
                return props.getProperty(name)
                    ?: throw IllegalStateException("Could not find property `$this` in `gradle.properties` or `local.properties`.")
            }

            return LocalVersions(
                kotlin = findProperty(kotlinVersionPropertyName)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

If I make a change to the value in `gradle.properties`, Gradle realizes that `buildSrc` has been modified. If I make a similar change to `local.properties`, Gradle doesn't realize a sync is needed. How can I instruct Gradle to realize this?